# Why is the potential difference across a conductor is equal to the battery voltage when it is connected to it

Tags: electric-circuits

Why is the potential differencel across the conductor is equal to  the battery voltage?

Comment: Suppose it wasn't? Then you'd either have energy vanishing or being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I thought the question was referring to a resistor, not a conductor.  If you connect an ideal conductor to the positive and negative terminals of a battery, then the simplified picture of conductors as equipotentials will break down.  To avoid this complication, you always need to include a resistor in such a circuit - otherwise the description becomes more complicated.

---

The wire connecting the positive terminal of the battery to the first terminal of the resistor is an equipotential, which means that the potential at the positive terminal of the battery is equal to the potential at the first terminal of the resistor.

For exactly the same reason, the potential at the second terminal of the resistor is equal to the potential at the negative terminal of the battery.  Therefore, the potential difference across the resistor is equal to the potential difference across the battery.